# using forecast accuracy function

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm using the `forecast` command on my time series.

When using the `accuracy` function, I get strange errors and results that I don't understand.

For example, when I do the following:

```
sinData <- ts(sin(2*pi*seq(from=0.01, to=10, by=0.01)), frequency=100)
fcast <- forecast(sinData)
accuracy(fcast, sinData)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in window.default(x, ...) : 'start' cannot be after 'end'
```

My first question is why do I get this error?

when I do the following:

```
sinData <- ts(sin(2*pi*seq(from=0.01, to=10, by=0.01)), frequency=100)
fcast <- forecast(sinData)
sinData <- ts(sin(2*pi*seq(from=0.01, to=10, by=0.01)))
accuracy(fcast, sinData)
```

I get:

```
                                ME           RMSE             MAE        MPE      MAPE         MASE ACF1 Theil's U
Training set         -7.570495e-18   1.080575e-15   6.783189e-16  -0.1144996  1.493135 1.065851e-15   NA        NA
Test set              5.669237e-01   5.669761e-01   5.669237e-01  85.9202023 85.920202 7.316031e+14 -0.5  11.86708
```

My second and main question is why do I get completely different errors between the "training set" and "test set", while clearly I use **exactly** the same data.

Answer (score 3):

1. The second argument in `accuracy` should be future data of the same period as the forecasts. Putting the historical data there will cause an error because it is from before the period of the forecasts.
2. In the second example you have tried to fool `accuracy` by changing the frequency attribute. `accuracy` will try to find the overlapping window of observations between the forecasts and the "future" data you have passed in the second argument. In this case, only a subset of the data are used because of the different frequency attributes.

The example in the help file for `accuracy()` shows how to use the function properly.

Comment: Your answers helped me greatly. However, according to your answer, accuracy is meant to test the forecast on true future data of the same dataset. My goal is to test my trained model on different datasets from same the sensor and from different ones, and distinguish between them according to their accuracy results. Isn't that the way you'd suggest? is there any better way to use forecast package to do this?